# Change to TableLayout for code in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have made a form for LinearLayout. It is of the following.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:hint="Num1" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edit2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:hint="Num2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Plus" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnSub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Minus" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnMul"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Multiple" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnDiv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Divide" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnSin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Sin" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnCos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Cos" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnTan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Tan" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnSqrt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="\u221A" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnSqr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="x^y" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnFact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="N!" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnPi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="\u03C0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="e" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnLog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Log(x)" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnLn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32sp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="ln" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:text="Result : "
    android:textColor="#00FFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have made a basic calculator. However,I don't know how to do it on GridLayout. 
I have a layout like this:

[image]

But I need this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help u....

Create new xml file in layout folder and then insert table layout by dragging it from widgets , by this u will create a table layout with 4 table rows.

choose which buttons should be placed in which row and then copy the respective button code into the particular table row .

Answer (score 0):

I'll just point you to this:

[**GRID LAYOUT XML Example**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout/)

You can use your elements, in place of those shown in the demo.

Comment: Thank you. I just used TableLayout.